# How can you get the sizeof an untyped type identifier, inside a macro?

Tags: nim-lang

More than willing to accept that this is an X:Y problem. here's the context:

I'm building a helper macro that parses a DSL of the form:

```
type
  FieldDescription[T; bitrange: static Slice[int]] = object 
  UnderlyingBitfield[size:static int, endianness: static Endianness, fields: tuple] = array[size,byte]

macro bitfield*(size:int,endianness:Endianness,fields:varargs[untyped]) = ...

type
  MyEnum = enum
    A,B,C 
  Foo = bitfield(size=4,bigEndian,
    field1 : uint8 31..28,
    field2 : MyEnum 27..25,
    )
```

I want to provide some static verification that those bitranges are valid for the given type, i.e.

```
  let fieldtype = getField(untyped_node)
  let (hi,lo) = getRange(untyped_node)
  if (hi - lo) >= sizeof(fieldtype)*8:
    error(&"bitrange {hi}..{lo} insufficient for type {fieldtype}")
```

Is there some way i can, i dunno,

```
macro foo(x:untyped) =
  var dummy:typeify(x)
  echo sizeof(dummy)
```

Or do i have to change my dsl to pass in those field parameters as 'typed' instead?  If so, how?

I can, of course simply construct the underlying tuple:

```
  type Foo = UnderlyingBitfield[4,bigEndian,tuple[
    field1:FieldDescription[uint8,31..28],
    field2:FieldDescription[MyEnum, 27..25]]]
```

or some version of that, and pass it in to something else to verify, but the object of the exercise is to allow for a clean, clear interface.

Yes, i know about `{.bitsize.}`  my issue with that is:

a) it doesn't allow for invisible padding fields

b) i still have to manually check alignment, endianness and offset for every type, because it's implementation defined and relies on the underlying c/c++ compiler

c) i want to specify these bitfields the way they come off the datasheet, and that is (hi..lo)

d) it clutters up my type definitions with a bunch of visual noise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to get type information from an `untyped` argument. As the name suggests it doesn't yet have a known type.

What I usually do is write one macro which takes in the `untyped` DSL, then I rewrite that to one or more call to typed calls. In your example for example, would it be possible to simply expand to a block which contains a bunch of asserts with `sizeof(x)` and then returns whatever you need? Or could you output a call to another macro which takes typed arguments?

---

*Fleshed out PMunch's answer for future reference --shirleyquirk*

For example:

```
import macros

type
  Foo[size:static int,thing] = array[size,byte]
  CTFoo = object
    size: int
    thing: NimNode

proc parseCTFoo(n:NimNode):CTFoo =
  result.size = n[1][1].intVal.int
  result.thing = n[1][2]

macro makeFoo(size:int,body:untyped):type =
  quote do:
    verify(Foo[`size`,`body`])

macro verify(x:typedesc[Foo]):untyped =
  let obj = x.getTypeInst.parseCTFoo
  if obj.size != obj.thing.getSize:
    error("size not equal to sizeof")
  x
```

```
type
  Bar = makeFoo(4,int)
#helpful compiletime error


type
  Baz = makeFoo(8,int)
#compiles fine
```

Comment: outputting a call to another macro would do it! i'll go try